# Android Google sign in api always call onResume()

Tags: android, onresume, google-signin

Today, I am try implement Google Sign in API: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
And implement interface 
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener on MainActivity(AppCompatActivity). However, everything ok in the first time sign in. When I open the new Activity and back again, onConnected() always called. How to avoid onConnected() called when MainAcivity onResume ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After the first time you login OK -> google sign-in return token key for client which you can save to client (use SharedPreference).

You can ref this code:

YOu need edit your code to similar:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestIdToken("server_client_id") //to require server return Id token
                .requestServerAuthCode("server_client_id") //to require server return authCode
                .build();

GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
String personId = acct.getId();
Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
String tokenKey = acct.getServerAuthCode(); //get authenticated code to save in client
```

2. Open activity/app again -> before do sign-in again you have to check token key is exiting (stored or not) -> if is exiting then you do not sign-in again and of cource connected in listener not occour

Cheer!

Comment: Hi @GiapLee, I am try your solutions and only getIdToken(), getServerAuthCode() are null, so, I cant save to SharedPreference. Any help ?

Comment: Yes. You can get any authen string from server to save into client.

Comment: Hi @GiapLee, getIdToken() and getServerAuthCode() are null

Comment: I am use MIUI os and Google Service version is 8.7. In project use google-services-auth:8.4.0. All are newest.

Comment: @ZNApps i have updated code. You need modify something about GoogleSignInOptions

Comment: Hi @GiapLee, I updated my code with 2 requests, and now, result code in onAcvitityResult is RESULTS_CANCELED = 0. Can not sign in. Here is code: GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
                    .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER), new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestIdToken("server_client_id")
                    .requestServerAuthCode("server_client_id")
                    .build();

Comment: YOu have to replace server_client_id string by client_id field in google-service.json or id you get from google console

Comment: Oh, sorry about vote, I will come back this post after reach least 15 reputations. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you must be having

```
google_api_client.connect()
```

in your onStart() method which will be connecting it again and again. You can fix it by creating a flag for SignInButton click and in onStart() method check for the flag before connecting the google_api_client.

Comment: No, I do not put connect() in onStart(), I will call it when press a custom button.